# What error is in this tld file?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a jsp file which refer to a tag lib sm.tld.

The browser say that:

`scripts.jsp:1:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/classes/sm.tld" prefix="sm" %>`

And here is the sm.tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN"   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib> 
<tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
<jspversion>2.0</jspversion>
<shortname>sm</shortname>
<uri></uri>
<tag>
    <name>topcategories</name>
    <tag-class>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.TopCategoriesTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>merchantId</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>int</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>maxCategories</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>int</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>lineBreakQuantity</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>int</type>
    </attribute>    
</tag>
<!-- Product Tag -->
<tag>
    <name>productimage</name>
    <tag-class>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.ProductImageTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>product</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>com.salesmanager.core.entity.catalog.Product</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>source</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>resizeratio</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>int</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>id</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>cssClass</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>addSchemeHostAndPort</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>boolean</type>
    </attribute>            
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>productprice</name>
    <tag-class>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.ProductPriceTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>product</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>com.salesmanager.core.entity.catalog.Product</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>displayCurrency</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>Boolean</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>productpricespecial</name>
    <tag-class>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.ProductPriceSpecialTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>product</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>com.salesmanager.core.entity.catalog.Product</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>displayCurrency</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>Boolean</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>productpricefinal</name>
    <tag-class>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.ProductPriceFinalTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>product</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>com.salesmanager.core.entity.catalog.Product</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>displayCurrency</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>Boolean</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>pageslinks</name>
    <tag-class>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.PagesLinksTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>merchantId</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>int</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>lineBreakQuantity</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>int</type>
    </attribute>    
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>languages</name>
    <tag-class>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.LanguagesTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>delimiter</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
        <name>param</name>
        <tagclass>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.ParameterTag</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
        <info>
            Set url parameter
        </info>
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>value</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
        <name>url</name>
        <tagclass>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.UrlTag</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
        <info>Url builds an encoded URL. (Inherit struts 2 url tag)</info>
        <attribute>
            <name>value</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>scheme</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>id</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>includeParams</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>includeContext</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>encode</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>action</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>namespace</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
        <name>forceAddSchemeHostAndPort</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>contents</name>
    <tagclass>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.ContentsTag</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
    <attribute>
        <name>merchantId</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>sectionId</name>
        <required>true</required>
    </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>content</name>
    <tagclass>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.ContentTag</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
    <attribute>
        <name>merchantId</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>title</name>
        <required>true</required>
    </attribute>
</tag>
<tag>
    <name>downloadUrl</name>
    <tagclass>com.salesmanager.core.util.www.tags.OrderProductDownloadTag</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
    <attribute>
    <name>productDownload</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

Please help me to find the error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a valid `<uri></uri>` here like `<uri>myFunctions</uri>` so that you can use the custom tag in your JSP as :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tt" uri="myFunctions" %>
```

Go through the official tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro9.html).

Or , you can use the `tagdir` attribute :

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/classes/sm.tld" prefix="sm" %>
```

Comment: You mean that the full path to the tag lib ?

Comment: How are you using the tags in your JSP ?

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/classes/sm.tld" prefix="sm" %>

Comment: Go through the tutorial , it should be `<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/classes/sm.tld" prefix="sm" %>`

Comment: The following taglib directive directly references a TLD file name: <%@ taglib prefix="tlt" uri="/WEB-INF/iterator.tld"%>

Comment: Use either `uri` or `tagdir` , `tagdir` is the location , `uri` is just a logical identifier . If you use `uri` define the same `uri` in the tld file.

Comment: The browser says: scripts.jsp:1:5: The taglib directive must specify either the "uri" or "tagdir" attribute.
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/classes/sm.tld" prefix="sm" %>